# AngularJS $q.all - wait between http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, settimeout

So I have a situation where I need to perform a bunch of http calls, then once they are complete, continue on to the next step in the process.

Below is the code which does this and works fine.

However, I now need to wait a few seconds between each of the http calls. Is there a way to pass in a timeout with my current set up, or will it involve a good bit of refactoring?

Can post more code if needs be. I have tried passing in a timeout config varable into the http call, however, they still get fired at the same time.

Any advice would be great.

Code

```
 var allThings = array.map(function(object) {
     var singleThingPromise = getFile(object.id);
     return singleThingPromise;
 });
 $q.all(allThings).then(function() {
     deferred.resolve('Finished');
 }, function(error) {
     deferred.reject(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$q.all`, you might want to perform sequential calls one on success of previous and probably with use of `$timeout`. Maybe you could build a recursive function.

Something like this..

```
function performSequentialCalls (index) {
  if(angular.isUndefined(array[index])) {
    return;
  }
  getFile(array[index].id).then(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      performSequentialCalls(index + 1)
    }, 1000) // waiting 1 sec after each call
  })
}
```

Inject required stuff properly. This assumes `array` to contain objects with `id`s using which you perform API calls. Also assumes that you are using `$http`. If using `$resource`, add `$promise` accordingly.

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Cheers! How would I call that given my set up above?

Comment: @user2085143 you can call that function where you want to start the API calls. And, if you see that `if` condition with `angular.isUndefined...`, you can write some code there (before `return`) which is required to be executed when all calls are complete.

Comment: Thanks a mil. Once I get some proper time i'll try it out and mark as correct if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getItemsWithDelay(index) {
  getFile(object[index].id).then(()=>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
     if(index+1 > object.length) { return }
     getItemsWithDelay(index+1)
  }, 5000)
 })
}
```

You can make sequential calls

Comment: How would I call that given my set up above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a awesome trick question to be asked in an interview, anyways I had a similar requirement and did some research on the internet and thanks to reference https://codehandbook.org/understanding-settimeout-inside-for-loop-in-javascript

I was able to delay all promise call in angularjs and the same can be applied in normal JS syntax as well.

I need to send tasks to a TTP API, and they requested to add a delay in each call

```
_sendTasks: function(taskMeta) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var promiseArray = [];
            const delayIncrement = 1000 * 5;
            let delay = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < taskMeta.length; i++) {
                // using 'let' keyword is VERY IMPORTANT else 'var' will send the same task in all http calls
                let requestTask = {
                    "action": "SOME_ACTION",
                    "userId": '',
                    "sessionId": '',                        
                };
                // new Promise can be replaced with $q - you can try that, I haven't test it although.  
                promiseArray.push(new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => $http.post(config.API_ROOT_URL + '/' + requestTask.action, requestTask), delay)));
                delay += delayIncrement;

            }
            $q.all(promiseArray).
            then(function(results) {
                    // handle the results and resolve it at the end
                    defer.resolve(allResponses);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    defer.reject("failed to execute");
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
```

Note:: using 'let' keyword in FOR loop is VERY IMPORTANT else 'var' will send the same task in all http calls - due to closure/context getting switched